# Traveling back to India on Indian passport with less than 6 months' validity

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I am an indian passport holder. My passport validity expiring in Feb 2024 and am planning to return to India in august. Will they let me in? Once I reach India will put my passport for reissue as I have to travel back where I work.